# Is there a simple way to use jQuery alongside Simile Timeplots?

Tags: jquery, simile

I created a loader for a [Simile Timeplot](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeplot/) that is implemented as a jQuery plugin. This works fine in Firefox but fails to load correctly in IE(8). The timeplot api loads the timeline api which in turn loads some version of jQuery (presumably an old version). The timeline jquery reference confuses IE and it is unable to display graphs nicely. If I do not reference a recent version of jQuery in my html then my loader fails because timeline has not yet been loaded or referenced jQuery.

There [looks to be](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/simile-widgets/browse_thread/thread/4eb02df298f707a7/084b957fbfdf82f4) some willingness to update timeline/timeplot with a modern jQuery but in the meantime, has anyone run into this problem and found a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this question helped me earn my tumbleweed badge and eventually we got timeplot working. However, today we finished migrating from Timeplot to Flot and I gotta say, if you're trying to combine Timeplot and jQuery, DON'T. Use Flot, it just works much better.